# Change interval timeouts of QTimer with slider

Tags: c++, qt

```
timer = new QTimer(this);
timer->setInterval(50);
QPushButton *start = new QPushButton("Start/Stop", this);
start->setText("Start/Stop");
layout->addWidget(start);
connect(start, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this]() {
   if (!timer->isActive()) {
      timer->start();
   } else {
      timer->stop();
          }
  });
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [&slider, sliderDisplay]() {
//increment slider value until at max, then reset to min
}
```

How can I use another slider to change the interval of timeouts emitted by my QTimer? I've tried using setInterval but it seems that I can't change the interval once it is set. Is the best way to do this just delete this QTimer and create a new QTimer with the specified interval every time?

Answer (score 6):

OP has claimed that

> How can I use another slider to change the interval of timeouts emitted by my QTimer? I've tried using setInterval but it seems that I can't change the interval once it is set.

I wondered a bit about that claim because I could've sworn that you can change the interval at any time.

The only restriction, I would consider: the new set interval might not be considered before the next timeout happens. (Usually, I use single-shot timers or timers with small intervals so that you wouldn't notice the difference.)

While playing with my demo, I got the impression that a call of `QTimer::setInterval()` restarts the interval.

Unfortunately, the doc. of [**QTimer::setInterval()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#interval-prop) doesn't mention this behavior explicitly, except:

> Setting the interval of an active timer changes its timerId().

Thanks to [@Scopchanov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64300917/change-interval-timeouts-of-qtimer-with-slider/64301362?noredirect=1#comment113716591_64301362) who had the look into source code (I was too lazy to).

[**QTimer::setInterval()**](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qtimer.cpp.html#_ZN6QTimer11setIntervalEi):

```
void QTimer::setInterval(int msec)
{
    inter = msec;
    if (id != INV_TIMER) {                        // create new timer
        QObject::killTimer(id);                        // restart timer
        id = QObject::startTimer(msec, Qt::TimerType(type));
    }
}
```

So, in fact, setting the interval while the timer is running, it kills the currently running timer and restarts a new one.

My [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for demonstration – `testQTimer.cc`:

```
// Qt header:
#include <QtWidgets>

// main application
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QWidget qWinMain;
  qWinMain.setWindowTitle("Test QTimer");
  QFormLayout qForm;
  QSlider qSliderInterval(Qt::Horizontal);
  qSliderInterval.setRange(100, 1000);
  qForm.addRow("Interval: ", &qSliderInterval);
  QSlider qSliderStep(Qt::Horizontal);
  qSliderStep.setRange(1, 10);
  qForm.addRow("Step: ", &qSliderStep);
  QPushButton qBtnStartStop("Start / Stop");
  qForm.addRow("Timer:", &qBtnStartStop);
  QSlider qSliderAnim(Qt::Horizontal);
  qForm.addRow("Animation:", &qSliderAnim);
  qSliderAnim.setRange(0, 100);
  qWinMain.setLayout(&qForm);
  qWinMain.show();
  // setup timer
  QTimer qTimer;
  qTimer.setInterval(qSliderInterval.value());
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qSliderInterval, &QSlider::valueChanged,
    [&](int value) { qTimer.setInterval(value); });
  QObject::connect(&qBtnStartStop, &QPushButton::clicked,
    [&]() {
      if (qTimer.isActive()) qTimer.stop();
      else qTimer.start();
    });
  QObject::connect(&qTimer, &QTimer::timeout,
    [&]() {
      int value = qSliderAnim.value() + qSliderStep.value();
      if (value > qSliderAnim.maximum()) {
        value -= qSliderAnim.maximum() - qSliderAnim.minimum();
      }
      qSliderAnim.setValue(value);
    });
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
Qt Version: 5.13.0
```

[image: snapshot of testQTimer.exe (animated)]

Comment: _While playing with my demo, I got the impression that a call of `QTimer::setInterval()` restarts the interval._ Your insight serves you well. :) To backup it up, here is the code of this method: [`inter = msec; if (id != INV_TIMER) { // create new timer
        QObject::killTimer(id);                        // restart timer
        id = QObject::startTimer(msec, Qt::TimerType(type));
    }`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qtimer.cpp.html#_ZN6QTimer11setIntervalEi). It does two things: 1. create(s a) new timer, 2. restart(s the) timer

Comment: @scopchanov Nice to here from you. I edited your remark in.

Comment: :) Hi, Scheff! It is very nice of you to add my comment to your already great answer. Thank you very much for this! Btw., it is nice to see (read from) you too.