# How can I put in a loop the change of a label in QT(c++)

Tags: c++, loops, qt, qtimer

I wrote this code , so I could monitor an ip address. I am using Qt and I want to make it, so when I press the button start it will ping the ip and return a value, like 1, which means that it is the minimum ping or whatever. The problem is that I cant put in a loop the change of a label. I tried QTimer but I couldn't figure it out. This is the code that I wrote:

```
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<ctime>
#include<fstream>
#include<QMessageBox>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<QTimer>
#include<QDebug>
using namespace std;


int check(string file){
    string a,b;
    int x,c;
    vector<int>ms;
    ifstream fin(file);
    while(!fin.eof()){
        getline(fin,a);
        if(a[0]=='P'){
            if(a=="PING: transmit failed. General failure. ")
                return -1;
        }
        if(a[0]=='R'){
            if(a=="Request timed out.")
                return -1;
            for(unsigned int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
                if(a[i]=='t'){
                    x=i+4;
                    while(a[x]!='m'){
                        b+=a[x];
                        x++;
                    }
                c=stoi(b);
                ms.push_back(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<ms.size();i++){
        if(ms[i]<20)
            return 0;
        else if(ms[i]>20 && ms[i]<60)
            return 1;
        else
            return 2;
    }
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
    ofstream fout("traffic.txt");
    string file_name="result.txt";
    QString a="ping ";
    QString b = ui->lineEdit->text();
    string result;
    int j=0;
    a+=b;
    string x=a.toStdString();
    QTimer timer;
    constexpr int interval =10;
    timer.callOnTimeout([&]{
    //qInfo()<<"ok";
      system((x+">" + file_name).c_str());
        //time_t now = time(0);
        //tm *ltm = localtime(&now);
        j=check(file_name);
        //Sleep(3000);
        if(j==0)
           ui->label_2->setText("ok");
        else if(j==1)
            ui->label_2->setText("minimum");
        else if(j==-1)
            QMessageBox::critical(this,"Error","request time out.Check the ip");
        else
            QMessageBox::critical(this,"bad","bad");
            //Sleep(30000);

           timer.start(interval);

    });
    timer.start(interval);
   }
```

Comment: FYI: [Qt doc.: Timers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/timers.html), [Qt Analog Clock Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-analogclock-example.html), and other examples in [SO: Change interval timeouts of QTimer with slider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64301362/7478597) and [SO: QTimer::timeout isn't firing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54840605/7478597) (and there are many more in SO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should connect your timer timeout signal to your lambda function instead of calling `timer.callOnTimeout`:

```
connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [this]() {
    .... your code
} );
```

also you don't need to start your timer again in your lambda function, because since you start it once, it will run continuously for it interval till you call `timer.stop()` .

Keep in mind that creating a Timer every time you push your button will create multiple instance of Timer that run simultaneously and will cause overload or memory overusing! try to use it more efficiently.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
    ofstream fout("traffic.txt");
    QTimer timer;
    constexpr int interval =10;

    connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [this]() {
    //qInfo()<<"ok";
    string file_name="result.txt";
    QString a="ping ";
    QString b = ui->lineEdit->text();
    string result;
    int j=0;
    a+=b;
    string x=a.toStdString();
      system((x+">" + file_name).c_str());
        //time_t now = time(0);
        //tm *ltm = localtime(&now);
        j=check(file_name);
        //Sleep(3000);
        if(j==0)
           ui->label_2->setText("ok");
        else if(j==1)
            ui->label_2->setText("minimum");
        else if(j==-1)
            QMessageBox::critical(this,"Error","request time out.Check the ip");
        else
            QMessageBox::critical(this,"bad","bad");
            //Sleep(30000);    
    });

    timer.start(interval);
   }
```

Comment: you mean just, replace timer.callOnTimeout with connect(&timer, &QQTimer::timeout, this, [this]() {  ?

Comment: Yes, you should replace your line `timer.callOnTimeout([&]{`  whith this `connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [this]() {`

Comment: I did that but now I have many errors for my variable x , j, file_name.  The error is variable x/j cannot be implicitly capture in a  lambda with no capture-default specified.

Comment: Yes it need refactoring, because they're it different scope.

Comment: `QTimer::callOnTimeout` is a convenience method for connecting to the timeout signal, so I don't really see how this would help. However, only capturing `this` pointed out some serious problems with the original design, where all variables where captured by reference, and then go out of scope... That's something that needs to be refactored

Comment: Sorry, guys but I really don't understand what do you mean by refactoring. Could you give me an exam on what should I do? Thanks.

Comment: @master_Ka1attas checkout my answer update