# QTimer: change interval while running, without restarting the interval

Tags: python, pyqt5

As mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64301362/2525940 calling `setInterval` on a `QTimer` restarts the interval.

I need a timer that takes account of the already elapsed time.

For example:
A QTimer is set to trigger every 5 minutes.
2 minutes after the previous trigger the operator (via the gui) sets the interval to 4 minutes.
The next trigger will happen 6 (2 + 4) minutes after the previous trigger. I need it to happen 4 minutes after the previous trigger, and then every 4 minutes.
I can stop the multishot timer, trigger a singleshot for (new_interval - old_interval + remainingTime), and then restart the multishot with the new_interval but this seems cumbersome.

Is there a better way?

Minimum code to show timer restarts when interval changed

```py
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.interval_seconds = 5
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.last_trigger = self.start_time

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(self.interval_seconds * 1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.trigger)
        self.timer.start()

        # Getting data from the first timer using another timer
        self.timer2 = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer2.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer2.timeout.connect(self.update_status)
        self.timer2.start()

        # GUI
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.interval = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.interval.setValue(self.interval_seconds)
        self.set_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Set interval")
        self.set_btn.clicked.connect(self.set_interval)
        self.text1 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
        self.text2 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.text3 = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Interval (s)"))
        layout.addWidget(self.interval)
        layout.addWidget(self.set_btn)
        layout.addWidget(self.text1)
        layout.addWidget(self.text2)
        layout.addWidget(self.text3)

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.show()

    def trigger(self):
        self.last_trigger = time.time()
        self.text1.appendPlainText(
            f"TRIGGER @ {(self.last_trigger - self.start_time):.1f}"
        )

    def update_status(self):
        time_gone = time.time() - self.last_trigger
        time_left = (self.timer.remainingTime() // 1000) + 1
        self.text2.setText(f"Elasped time        (s) {time_gone:.1f} ")
        self.text3.setText(f"Next trigger in ... (s) {time_left:.1f} ")

    def set_interval(self):
        self.interval_seconds = self.interval.value()
        self.timer.setInterval(self.interval_seconds * 1000)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: The way I handle this sort of thing is to set a member-variable to the absolute-timestamp of when I want the next event to occur (e.g. `self.eventTime = time.time() + 5.0`); then whenever I want to set (or stop and re-set) a QTimer to go off at that time, it's just a matter of calculating `self.eventTime-time.time()` to know what value to pass to the QTimer.  (Be sure to force negative values up to zero, and be sure to update `self.eventTime` to something larger after the event's time arrives, to avoid busy-looping)

Comment: If the timer was single shot, then it would just be a matter of `timer.setInterval(max(0, newInterval - timer.interval() + timer.remainingTime())`. But you want to reset its "default" interval also, which calls for a subclass: you could override `setInterval()`, keep a reference to the new interval as an instance attribute, call the base implementation using the formula above, and then override its `timerEvent()`, which would eventually reset the timer using the stored interval but using the default implementation (through `super()`).

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jeremy Friesner comment this works and looks OK. It makes deliberate use of the setInterval restarting the multishot timer.

```py
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.interval_seconds = 5
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.last_trigger = self.start_time

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(self.interval_seconds * 1000)

        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.trigger)
        self.timer.start()

        # Getting data from the first timer using another timer
        self.timer2 = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer2.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer2.timeout.connect(self.update_status)
        self.timer2.start()

        # GUI
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.interval = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.interval.setValue(self.interval_seconds)
        self.set_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Set interval")
        self.set_btn.clicked.connect(self.set_interval)
        self.text1 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
        self.text2 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.text3 = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Interval (s)"))
        layout.addWidget(self.interval)
        layout.addWidget(self.set_btn)
        layout.addWidget(self.text1)
        layout.addWidget(self.text2)
        layout.addWidget(self.text3)

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.show()

    def trigger(self):
        self.last_trigger = time.time()
        self.text1.appendPlainText(
            f"TRIGGER @ {(self.last_trigger - self.start_time):.1f}"
        )
        self.timer.setInterval(self.interval_seconds * 1000)

    def update_status(self):
        time_gone = time.time() - self.last_trigger
        time_left = (self.timer.remainingTime() // 1000) + 1
        self.text2.setText(f"Elasped time        (s) {time_gone:.1f} ")
        self.text3.setText(f"Next trigger in ... (s) {time_left:.1f} ")

    def set_interval(self):
        self.interval_seconds = self.interval.value()
        next_interval_seconds = self.last_trigger + self.interval_seconds - time.time()
        next_interval_ms = max(0, int(next_interval_seconds * 1000))
        self.timer.setInterval(next_interval_ms)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to create a subclass of QTimer and implement a different logic by overriding `setInterval()`, then restore the "actual" interval after it times out the first time by overriding `timerEvent`, which is where `timeout` is normally emitted.

Note that since it's possible that a function connected to `timeout` would eventually restart it or change its interval on its own, we should block signals while calling the base implementation, and emit the signal *after* eventually resetting it.

```py
class MyTimer(QTimer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._interval = super().interval()

    def interval(self):
        self._interval

    def setInterval(self, interval):
        self._interval = interval
        if self.isActive():
            current = super().interval()
            if interval > current:
                interval -= current - self.remainingTime()
        super().setInterval(interval)

    def timerEvent(self, event):
        block = self.blockSignals(True)
        super().timerEvent(event)
        self.blockSignals(block)
        if self._interval != super().interval():
            super().setInterval(self._interval)
        self.timeout.emit()
```